# How to check which credential Azure python SDK class DefaultAzureCredential is using for login

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-identity, azure-python-sdk

I'm using Azure SDK for python in the machine learning env and to create a Workspace instance I'm using the following code.

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azureml.core import Workspace

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
Workspace.from_config()
```

How to I know which type of credential Azure is using to authenticate my ML Studio Compute instance? I've read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python#environment-variables) that shows that the `DefaultAzureCredential` class try 5 different types of credential. Yesterday I was having some kind of problems authenticating and I had to enable a Manage Identity in my ML Studio Compute instance and add the manage identity as a contributor in the IAM of the Azure Machine Learning Studio service but today with a new machine I'm having no trouble with the authentication.

In yesterday authentication I had to authenticate using the CLI command

```
az login --identity --username $DEFAULT_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: I don't know how to check which one is used but you can see the order that the class is using here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-python

And if you would like to use a specific one, you could use the `exclude_`-parameters. It's not the answer to your question but maybe still helpful. :-)

Comment: I was helpfull for sure! Thank you Jason!

Answer (score 1):

You can set `logging_enable` to `True` when creating a `DefaultAzureCredential` object. This will then log which mechanism is being used. Just remember to configure logging in your app!

```py
import logging
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

cred = DefaultAzureCredential(logging_enable=True)
```

Any `get_token()` calls will show additional information including HTTP calls to AAD to help you see what is going on.

If you want a bit more control over which mechanisms you want to use then look at the [`ChainedTokenCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.chainedtokencredential?view=azure-python) class.

Bit late, but hopefully will be useful to people.

Comment: Do you know how I can see the logs using Azure Application Insights?