# AzureDefaultCredentials fail with Authorization Code: None

Tags: azure-python-sdk, azure-entra-id

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110869/how-to-check-which-credential-azure-python-sdk-class-defaultazurecredential-is-u) question.
I'm running this code locally in VSCODE, and am logged in using `az login`.  I've also tried `aad_credentials = AzureCliCredential()` with the same result. Left out the details of creating the group.

```
aad_credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
URI = environ.get("DPS_ENDPOINT")
client = DeviceProvisioningClient(endpoint=URI, credential=aad_credentials)
group_id = 'symetric_group_test'
enrollment_group = {
    "enrollmentGroupId": group_id,
    "attestation": {
        "type": "symmetricKey"
    }
}
client.enrollment_group.create_or_update( id=group_id, enrollment_group=enrollment_group
```

Response:

```
azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: (None) Authorization failed for the request
Code: None
Message: Authorization failed for the request
```

adding `logging_enable=True` did not provide any output.

Anything hints or directions on how to debug?

UPDATE: Same error in Azure Cloud Shell.

this might be the issue.  I have permissions in portal, but in clis:

az role assignment list --assignee 
[]

Comment: Could you confirm whether you are trying to login as user or managed identity while running `az login` command? Please include complete code by editing your question.

Comment: @Sridevi - logging in with my username at az login.

Comment: What RBAC roles you currently have under subscription, please add Azure Portal screenshot by editing your question?

Answer (score 0):

@Sridevi was correct.  It was a permissions issue.
`Device Provisioning Service Data Contributor` is the required permission.
I think a 403 (I know who you are and you lack permission) would be a better code than None.  Although it might be more useful to post that in github.